# Disable shift key capitalisation

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, capslock, shift

When I want to type a capital letter, I always use Caps Lock. I use shift for symbols like _.

I find it much easier to use Caps Lock for capital letters since you just have to press it, and then your hand is free to type the key you want, capitalized. Whereas, with shift, you have to hold it down at the same time as pressing a key, which is uncomfortable if you do a lot of typing (for me at least).

I find myself accidentally capitalizing letters which I don't mean to, because of the shift key. For example, when I type `my_video`, I sometimes accidentally type `my_Video` because the shift key is still down, and it is hard to sync my hands up when I type fast.

I would like to disable shift from capitalizing letters; but keep it enabled for controlling whether the numbers appear as numbers or symbols (1 or ! for example).

To clarify, if Caps Lock is disabled, I don't want any capital/uppercase letters, regardless of what shift says.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I forgot to mention, Windows 7.

Comment: Because Caps is just cruise control for Shift ;), I don’t think you can achieve what you want. Better learn proper timing/typing.